# c# excel определить последнюю ячейку

Tags: c#, excel

Есть xls файл, созданный сторонней программой. В нем 28 030 подряд вниз заполненных ячеек в столбце. Используя

```
excelcells = excelworksheet.get_Range("A1");
int lastRow = excelworksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
```

получил, как и положено, lastRow = 28030;
Затем в этом файле вручную удалил нижнюю часть ячеек, осталось 28 007. Все так же идущие подряд. Используя все те же строчки кода, lastRow = 28016; Пробовал несколько раз удалять (и добавлять больше, чем было) ячейки. При удалении/добавлении иногда последнюю определяет правильно, иногда нет. В других аналогичных файлах ситуация повторяется. Как же 100% правильно определить нижнюю не пустую ячейку?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ по операторам *VBA-Excel*. Похоже, рекомендации применимы и к этому вопросу.

*UsedRange* - пользовательский диапазон. Но он может начинаться не с первой строки на листе и заканчиваться не последней строкой с даными. Это диапазон, в котором производились какие-либо действия.

На новом листе в строке 5 рисуем шапку таблицы, вносим 10 строк данных. В данном случае *UsedRange.Rows.Count* = 11 (10 строк + заголовки).

Удаляем данные из последней строки. Диапазон не изменился - последняя строка в диапазоне пользователя.

Удаляем последнюю строку таблицы. И? Нет, в диапазоне пользователя по прежднему 11 строк. А вот если после удаления строки сохранить изменения - *UsedRange.Rows.Count* = 10. Наконец-то избавились... Если же сохраниться после удаления данных, то не факт, что диапазон уменьшится - ячейки отформатированы.

Еще ситуация. Копирование из другой таблицы. Копируют не глядя - *Copy/Paste* целыми столбцами. И часто-густо книга с данными в сотню строк имеет мегабайтный вес. Причина? Копировалось все, в том числе и форматы нижних строк, в которых данных нет, но с которыми раньше усиленно работали.

Последняя рабочая строка на листе с учетом возможных незадействованных строк сверху:

```
With excelworksheet
    LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Row - 1
End With
```

Для примера с таблицей: 11 + 5 - 1 = 15
Следует помнить, что будут учтены и форматированные строки (вернее: строки с форматированными ячейками) без данных.

Последнюю строку с данными можно определять другим способом:

```
With excelworksheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Здесь единичка - столбец А (можно писать имя столбца - "A").

Этот метод тоже имеет недостаток. Так определится последняя ячейка с данными, но в отображаемых строках. Если на листе применен фильтр и посление строки с данным скрыты, *LastRow* покажет меньшее число.

Если заранее неизвестно, будут ли пустые форматированные ниже диапазона с данными и будут ли скрытые строки, можно задействовать один из вариантов:

- определить нижнюю строку *UsedRange*, в цикле проверить наличие данных и найти последнюю заполненную ячейку;
- принудительно отобразить все строки и применить *End(xlUp).Row*

Comment: В строке `LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` половину подчеркнуло красным, в т.ч.первую точку.

Comment: Не знаю синтаксиса C#.  Возможно, такого метода в C# нет. Поищите замену. В *VBA* родителя можно указать под *With*. Уберите  строки *With/End With* и перед точками запишите *excelworksheet*.

Comment: *LastRow = excelworksheet.Cells(excelworksheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row* или *LastRow = excelworksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row*  Перед *Row* нужно, если работа идет с разными форматами книг (.xls имеет 65000 строк, .xlsx - более миллиона)